# Apps seem to be "lost connection" with MobileFirst/backend server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

If we keep our WL apps in background for a while, they seem to be lost connection with the MF server. I thought this could be related with features defined in `application-descriptor.xml` as there's a `accessTokenExpiration` attribute with a value of `3600`, and the MF server logged errors below:

```
[ERROR   ] FWLSE4007E: Received bad token from client. Server token:'46ejj4elqjtg3vrn8j4qaql8es', client token:'2kvma3lscib0h1q5dlu7mak818'. [project Dummy]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE4007E: Received bad token from client. Server token:'k8irk7mftj0j4ostbbba7smqto', client token:'mptvg1t1l4n8e7qfr1ratrcf30'. [project Dummy]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE4007E: Received bad token from client. Server token:'dhfjgut9aku08hcm88rlb9rjo2', client token:'46ejj4elqjtg3vrn8j4qaql8es'. [project Dummy]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE4007E: Received bad token from client. Server token:'mdva1p1nt428oii6nvd91n7vu5', client token:'46ejj4elqjtg3vrn8j4qaql8es'. [project Dummy]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE4007E: Received bad token from client. Server token:'jmbvd7ocaoj4gb709n0b3mh62g', client token:'dhfjgut9aku08hcm88rlb9rjo2'. [project Dummy]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE4007E: Received bad token from client. Server token:'tv1t1blffk8sekc1422oq6s64a', client token:'mdva1p1nt428oii6nvd91n7vu5'. [project Dummy]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE4007E: Received bad token from client. Server token:'sh06en0ihc0i7dvd77fpkrj57s', client token:'jmbvd7ocaoj4gb709n0b3mh62g'. [project Dummy]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE4007E: Received bad token from client. Server token:'6070lc7pafqusf4jslhsh8a49b', client token:'tv1t1blffk8sekc1422oq6s64a'. [project Dummy]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE4007E: Received bad token from client. Server token:'vhds5i92t64pkfn3htdcjr3749', client token:'6070lc7pafqusf4jslhsh8a49b'. [project Dummy]
```

So it's a too short time that connection expires. And how can we can make a "remember me" function between MobileFirst and the client that unless the end-users quit the app, otherwise they will always being logged in?

Comment: Are you saying that `3600` is too short? (In which case, did you try a higher number?). Or are you saying that it's not really `3600` seconds?

Comment: @NathanH just in case that you leave the app in the background and do not kill them. After a cup of tea time when you back, the app is frozen and the session with WL server expired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure expiration tokes in the server\conf\worklight.properties file.

There is also a "Remember Me" tutorial and sample application, based on MobileFirst Platform 7.1: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/advanced-topics/remember-me/

Comment: Wow, it seems that I've never touched this configure file... and also I have to re-deploy a new war file? Still working on MFP 7.0

Comment: Changes to this file require .war file re-deployment.

Comment: The sample implementation is fine for 7.0 as well.

Comment: @Adar really a long tutorial ... And I just tried in mfp 7.0, it seems that `Cloudant` related source are not included inside the project, do I have to import cloudant related jars to classpath?

Comment: Find it here : https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant/releases and http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/cloudant/cloudant-client/1.1.2/cloudant-client-1.1.2.jar

Comment: @Adar if we just simply want all logged in user never lost connect with the WL server unless they quit or log out , can we just make all values set to be `-1` `in worklight.properties` and do not do anything related in the tutorial ?

Comment: @Sam, see Nathan's reply below.

Comment: @IdanAdar The link you've mentioned is expired. Use this instead https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/advanced-topics/remember-me/

Comment: @IdanAdar I am facing same problem. Even in worklight.properties file serverSessionTimeout is commented. Can you please help or suggest some solution?

Answer (score 1):

### Session timeout

In the **server\conf\worklight.properties** file, take a look at the property named `serverSessionTimeout`.

The default is 10 minutes which means that if the server does not get any request from that client within 10 minutes, the session will expire with everything attached to it. As long as the user is active, the session is renewed. Keep in mind that a longer session timeout may increase the server's memory usage.

There is also a feature called **heartbeat**, that sends a ping to the server to keep the session alive, but this only works when your application is in the **foreground**.

If your application is native, I guess you could implement your own heartbeat to keep it alive.

### Token expiration

In the **application-descriptor.xml**, the element `accessTokenExpiration` will define the default OAuth token expiration for this specific application. The default is 3600 seconds (1 hour). Which means that from the moment the user logs in, they have 1 hour of trusted access, whether or not they are active.

### Realm expiration

In the **authenticationConfig.xml** file, each `loginModule` has a `expirationInSeconds` property. Similar to the one above, it will define how long is the user trusted after they logged-in to this specific login module / realm. When the expiration happens, the server will send a new challenge for the associated realm.

In 7.0, `-1` means the user is trusted until `serverSessionTimeout` happens. In 7.1, `-1` is no longer a valid value.

If any of the above is expired, the client may need to get a new token. Depending on the expiration of each `loginModule`, the user may or may not receive a new challenge.

### Remember Me Sample

The RememberMe sample (https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/advanced-topics/remember-me/) uses the idea of storing the unique Client-ID to an external database to automatically login the user when his session has expired.

Comment: +1 for the clear explanation of the "mess up" concepts in `worklight.properties` and `application-descriptor.xml`. From @Adar and your answers I've known that the best practise would be doing a similar function as the "Remember Me" tutorial. And I think this tutorial could be a easier demo if without the IBM Cloudant part :-)

Comment: @Nathan I am facing same problem. I have checked all the files but still getting Received bad token exception. Also around mid time I found lots of FWLSE4007E: Received bad token from client priting on WAS(MFP) server log files. What will be the reason for these? Can you please help me out?